# Secure a REST interface without login

Tags: rest

I recently succeeded in building a page that loads data via an ajax get call to a REST interface (that runs on my server) and then uses the data to construct a map overlay for Google maps via JS.
I managed to do this but now I have concerns about the security of my data. Obviously everybody could just use curl to load the overlay data from my REST interface. However, I do not want to make my data so easily available, since they are kind of the business value of my page...

Is saw many solutions on the web that all require a login of the user.
However, this should not be required on my page.
Is there an easy solution to this problem, without the user having to use a log in or something? Basically I only want to allow my web application to query data from my REST interface, but not anyone else.

One solution that came to my head is to pass the data directly from php into JS, when the page is loaded. However this looks like a real ugly solution to me...

Comment: Depending on if your server has a static IP, just check the requesters IP?

Comment: You won't be able to protect your data without some sort of end user identification. Either you supply an API that serves the data - and that makes it "too easily available", or you embed it in a web page as you suggest (directly from PHP into JS) in which case it becomes more difficult to read the data automatically - but by no means impossible, as someone can now use a client like CURL to access all your web pages and extract the data from the embedded JS. If you want public accessibility you have to face the fact that your data will be available to anyone who can screen scrape your site.

Answer (score 0):

On a RESTful interface, I suppose you want to avoid login into a session. You have basically 2 more ways :

- use IP address filtering if the web application run on a private network with known IP addresses
- pass an identification token in the request headers or as a request parameter. The token has to be passed along in all the requests.